# Return a different column from the same row in SQL query

Tags: database, vb.net, ado.net

I am working on a project where I am interacting with a remote MySQL database.  Everything is working fine, and I am ready to move on.  I have successfully executed several queries, one of which, was to return (true or false) if a particular record existed in the database.  That part works great.  Now what I want to do is not execute a boolean search, but rather return the actual value of another cell in the same row where the boolean search returned true (I hope that makes sense).  In other words, if a string exists in column 0 of row 100, I want to return the value of column 3 in row 100.

Here is the current code:

```
    Private Function LicenseExists(argKey As String) As Boolean
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim connection As MySqlConnection
    connection = New MySqlConnection()
    connection.ConnectionString = "Server=domain.com; Uid=username; Pwd=password; Database=db_name;"
    strQuery = "SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name=?somevalue"
    Using SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, connection)
        SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?somevalue", argKey)
        connection.Open()
        Using reader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
            Return reader.Read()
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: This would be a good time to take a break, grab a coffee (or other suitable beverage), and read through some tutorials on SQL and ADO.NET ..

Comment: @pst  lol, Yeah I have been doing that and I knew about the SELECT query, but couldn't figure out how to return the value instead of true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Simply...

```
strQuery = "SELECT column_name, other_column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name=?somevalue"
```

where `other_column_name` is the other column you're interested in.

And then to get the value...

```
While reader.Read
    cboMessage.Items.Add(New clsMessage(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("other_column_name"))))
End While
```

Comment: Thank you Ian.  So would I just change the "as Boolean" to "as String"?

Comment: Awesome! Trying it now. Thanks again.  --John

Comment: Got it, thank you!  I was going nuts because it was still returning the boolean result!  Now I can take an aspirin, have a coffee and relax!